# Is there a way to put a driver on Emission Count in a Hair Particle system?

Tags: objects, particles, drivers, groups, procedural

I am working on a way to populate random details along a single edge (like windows doors, garage doors, ..etc), in an attempt to create semi procedural buildings. So far I have found that using a hair emitter and a group containing my detail objects seems to get a partial result that I am after. I can easily populate the hairs along the vertices in the single edge, and then use a shapekey to control how long the edge can expand, and maintain even distances between the vertices.

[image]

However, because I am using this method, I can't have the particles emitting, 12 particles on all 12 vertices, when my control edge is smaller/contracted. This can cause chaos!

[image]

While I could set the number lower manually, this is not ideal as when I start to populate my scene it would slow down production if I would have to constantly adjust that value. I already have a driver that is working the expansion of both my building base and my hair emitter path and logically I would like the driver to also work the hair emitter emission number. Can anyone help?